# Installing Requirements.txt results in Invalid Syntax Error Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, requirements.txt

I have been trying to install a requirements.txt file but I get a SyntaxError: Invalid Syntax when I try to install it.

I have the requirements.txt file in the same folder as my python.exe file.

I have tried:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Results in:

```
File "stdin", line 1    (the stdin is inside angled brackets)

pip install -r requirements.txt

           ^

SyntaxError: Invalid Syntax
```

Same result running this:

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

I expected the requirements.txt to be installed. I get the syntax error message instead.

Comment: There's an error in your requirements file, post that (also spell it 'requirements').

Comment: Check [this](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirements-file-format) for proper formatting guide for requirements.txt.

Comment: First, my apologies for the error.  I had correctly been using requirements.txt in my attempts, but ended up typing too quickly here and messed that up.  

Here is the requirements.txt contents:

requests==2.21.0
beautifulsoup4==4.7.1

Comment: I rolled back your latest edit. If you have a new unrelated issue, (accept one of the answers here and) post a new question; but absolutely not as a screen shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `pip install -r requirments.txt` from command line, not from python console. 
If the program is not available use `python -m pip install -r requirments.txt`

Comment: I just tried doing both versions (pip and pip3) from cmd and got the following:
pip3 is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file

Comment: Because maybe pip3 is not installed!

Comment: Would pip/pip3 have not been installed when I installed Python 3.7?

Comment: so check if `python -m pip install -r requirments.txt` will work

Comment: I get the error that "python" is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file when typing that into cmd.   I also checked, the Python I installed is 3.7.4

Comment: I added Python to path and now at least I know Python is fully installed.

Comment: Now I get the following: Could not open requirements file: [Errno2] No such file or directory 'requirements.txt'           Then a long message about being unable to fetch a URL.

Comment: Did you run the commant in same directory where is requirements.txt file?

Comment: Please see my original post which I just updated with my attempt (see picture linked at bottom).  I THINK the CMD is now finding the requirements file, but it's not finding the stuff.
https://imgur.com/a/C94trEk

Thank you to everyone who has helped so far!

Comment: Now you have totally different problem (network configuration). Please see this thread: https://python-forum.io/Thread-Cannot-update-or-install-anything-with-pip-SSL-error